# Page Template select list not appearing in WordPress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using a WordPress child theme and the Page Template select list is not appearing when I create or edit a page. My page templates are set up correctly. They all start with:

/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

Comment: so what's the issue? is the template not appearing in the list of templates when editing / creating a new blog post / page or it is appearing, it just has no effect?

Comment: The issue was that the Template select list was not appearing in the Page Attributes widget at all. I followed the suggestion below and noticed that I was missing the index.php file in the child theme. After adding it I was able to see and select page templates.

Comment: if the answer helped you, please make sure you accept it as the correct one (big gray check mark)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your child theme is set up correctly? Navigate to Appearance > Themes and make sure there is not an error message that templates are missing.

I had this issue before, and after adding the index.php file from the parent theme I was able to change the page templates in the child theme.

Comment: @webeno: Actually, if you check OP comment on question, apparently this answer did help him solve the issue.

Comment: hm... looks to be the case, indeed.